# How to call a subprogram inside of another subprogram?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, function-call

I've recently started work upon a project that converts Postfix expressions entered by the user into prefix and infix expressions respectably. However, I have run into issues with calling these subprograms within other subprograms as I am not exactly sure how they function. What I would like to do is call the strcat subprogram within the postfix_to_prefix subprogram, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to go about it.

This project is for a Computer Architecture class and I have spent around 10 hours so far trying to do personal research on how to write the program, but I've failed to find what I must do in order for it to function correctly, specifically in the operation label of the code.

```
; A Subprogram that converts Postfix Prefix
segment .data
plus_sign   db ' + ', 0
minus_sign  db ' - ', 0
multiply    db ' * ', 0
divider     db ' / ', 0
parenthsf   db ' ( ', 0
parenthsb   db ' ) ', 0

segment .bss    
operand     resd 1
operators   resd 1

segment .text


postfix_to_infix:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp

    mov     eax, 0
    mov     esi, 0
    mov     edi, 0
    mov     ebx, [ebp + 8]                      ; ebx = infix
    mov     ecx, [ebp + 16]                     ; ecx = post_len
    mov     edx, [ebp + 12]                     ; edx = postfix

comparison:
    mov     al, [edx + esi]
    cmp     al, '+'
    je      operation
    cmp     al, '-'
    je      operation
    cmp     al, '*'
    je      operation
    cmp     al, '/'
    je      operation
    cmp     al, ' '
    je      opexit

    inc     esi
    push    eax
    loop    comparison


operation:
    mov     [operators], eax
    pop     eax
    mov     [operand], eax
    pop     eax

    ;This point here is what I specifically need to figure out...
    pusha
    push    dword[operand]  
    push    eax
    call    strcat
    add     esp,8
    popa


opexit:
    inc     esi
    loop    comparison

    pop ebx
    pop ebp
    ret



; A subprogram strcat appends the contents of one string to the end of another
; strcat(str1,str2)
; Result: str1= str1 + str2
; stored in str1
segment .bss
append_length   resd 1
read_length     resd 1
segment .text
strcat: 
    push    ebp                             ; 
    mov     ebp, esp                        ;
    mov     edx, [ebp+12]                   enter code here; what we want to append

    push    edx                             ;
    call    length_is                       ;
    add     esp, 4                          ;
    mov     [append_length], eax            ;
    mov     eax, 0                          ;

    mov     ebx, [ebp+8]                    ; original string str1

    push    ebx                             ;
    call    length_is                       ;
    add     esp, 4                          ;
    mov     [read_length], eax              ;
    mov     eax, 0                          ;

    mov     ebx, [ebp+8]                    ; original string str1
    mov     edx, [ebp+12]                   ; what we want to append
    mov     ecx, [append_length]            ;
    mov     edi, 0                          ;
    mov     esi, [read_length]              ; the last location of original string is where to append 

append_loop:
    mov     al, [edx+edi]                   ;
    mov     [ebx+esi], al                   ;
    add     esi, 1                          ;
    add     edi, 1                          ;
    loop    append_loop                     ;

    pop     ebp                             ;
    ret
```

The program is meant to convert postfix to prefix and display it to the user. I need help figuring out how to call these subprograms or how I could use them in order to get the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously if you use `pusha`/`popa` around a function call, `popa` destroys the return value in EAX, replacing it with whatever was in EAX before the call.  Don't do that.

Just let functions clobber the call-clobbered registers (EAX, ECX, and EDX in the i386 System V calling convention<sup>1</sup>), and use those registers for temporaries or whatever that don't need to survive across a function call.

---

Footnote 1: And pretty much all other 32-bit x86 calling conventions.  But if you ever want to look up more details about how to pass args (e.g. to functions that take a struct), you can look at C compiler output, or look up the i386 System V ABI doc.